# Bootstrap Select dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i have a requirement to customize the bootstrap select dropdown box, where 
 the "caret" will be changed by an image/png.
How to achieve that. Most of the examples i found online are straight forward...couldn't find any correct solution. Please help

Comment: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but something like

```
<span class="glyphicon">Dropdown Text<img src="img.png" /></span>
```

Can't look into it more at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to override the caret css class, in order to include an image instead of the classic triangle.

An example in this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/fALAlLzM9O).

CSS:

```
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background:url('http://pesos.pes.edu/images/icons/facebook.png') center no-repeat;                           
}
```